# Files not uploading when using winscp

Tags: ftp, winscp

I am uploading files with winscp a lot and I figured out that uploading files takes too long or dont even happen. I'm editting files that are on winscp and save them to it as well. Whenever I do this, I have to close the file and then open the file again and make some more (very minor) changes before the file will actually be uploaded to my destination. This has nothing to do with upload speed since when I do this, it takes 5 minutes or less everytime I make a change to the file and it actually registering the changes. Whenever I make one edit and it's not shown immediatly and I wait a day, it still hasn't uploaded yet.

My question is, would this be something with Winscp or most likely not?

If so, how do I stop this and make sure it uploads immediatly? This makes my work extremely slow and frustrating that I have to make a lot of minor changes to get it to work.(sometimes I spend like 10 minutes just to get 2 lines of text/code to upload)

Comment: Do you download edit upload or you edit directly on winscp?
What is the size of your regular files?

Comment: @emirjonb I edit directly on winscp. Size of my regular files are like 3kb.

Comment: what software do you use for editing? have you tried the long way download>edit>upload, does it take 5 min again?

Comment: @emirjonb I'm going to do it that way now. I'm installing all the software I need to actually test it locally and then upload it and see if it gives the same result. This still wont tell me what's going wrong though.

Comment: maybe is your editing software that cause this, if the simple upload is done  normally. you can try something like notepadd++ and direct edit

Comment: @emirjonb I tried different editing software. Also whenever I open the file in winscp, it shows the edits I made but still no different result as in like when I make software.

Comment: what if you upload a single file from desktop to ftp server is the same latency ?